# Nodejs handle error

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm new at NodeJS and i got always this same error :

> /var/www/html/helpdesk/node_modules/ent/encode.js:8
>           throw new TypeError('Expected a String');
>           ^
>
> TypeError: Expected a String
>       at Object.encode (/var/www/html/helpdesk/node_modules/ent/encode.js:8:15)
>       at Socket. (/var/www/html/helpdesk/apps.js:32:22)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
>       at /var/www/html/helpdesk/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:503:12
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9) /var/www/html/helpdesk/node_modules/ent/encode.js:8
>           throw new TypeError('Expected a String');
>           ^

How to handle this?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var ent = require('ent'); 
var fs = require('fs');


io.on('connection', function(socket){

        socket.emit('message', { content: 'Vous êtes bien connecté ! ', importance: '1' });


        socket.on('message', function (message) {
            /*console.log('Un client me parle ! Il me dit : ' + message);
             console.log(socket.pseudo + ' me parle ! Il me dit : ' + message);
             io.sockets.emit('message', { content: 'Vous êtes bien connecté ! '+
             socket.pseudo, importance: '1' });*/

            message = ent.encode(message);
            io.sockets.emit('message', {pseudo: socket.pseudo, message: message});
        });

        socket.on('pseudo', function(pseudo) {
            pseudo = ent.encode(pseudo);
            socket.pseudo = pseudo;
        });

        socket.on('nouveau_client', function(pseudo) {
            if(pseudo.length >= 1 && typeof pseudo=="string"){
                pseudo = ent.encode(pseudo);
                socket.pseudo = pseudo;
                io.sockets.emit('nouveau_client', pseudo);
            }

        });



});
```

Comment: Pass a string? Put here what are you trying to do

Comment: You need to show YOUR code that triggers this exception.

Comment: The error may come from this line **message = ent.encode(message);**   `    
    var ent = require('ent'); 
 var fs = require('fs');
...........
                   socket.on('message', function (message) {       
                **message = ent.encode(message);**
                io.sockets.emit('message', {pseudo: socket.pseudo, message: message});
            });
..............

Answer (score 1):

It would definitely be far more helpful for you to include more information about your code and what you are trying to do. In the spirit of helping though I can make some assumptions.

It looks like you are using socket.io. It also looks like you are using the `emit` function. Maybe something like `socket.emit(thing)` or `io.emit(thing)`. My guess is that `thing` is not a string. You can check it or `JSON.stringify()` it to see!

Comment: The error may come from this line  **message = ent.encode(message);**   `    
    var ent = require('ent'); 
 var fs = require('fs');
...........
                   socket.on('message', function (message) {       
                **message = ent.encode(message);**
                io.sockets.emit('message', {pseudo: socket.pseudo, message: message});
            });
..............